# Prove or disprove that the set of polynomials of degree greater than or equal to two, along with the zero polynomial is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This was disproved by giving the example:
$$(x^2)+(1+x-x^2)$$

The result is NOT in the set so it's NOT closed under addiction, so NOT a vector space.

But I was looking for some prove that doesn't use example to show that is not closed under addiction. Can someone do this?

Edit: sorry wrong typing.

Comment: The negation of "for all $v, u \in V, v + u \in V$ is "there exists $u, v \in V$ such that $u + v \notin V$. What better way to show that something exists than just providing it? Your request is extremely strange.

Comment: The example shows a case where the greater degree polynomial is getting canceled, I was trying to put this into words.

Comment: You can derive the general form of a counter example. You can set the sum of two arbitrary polynomials of degree two or higher to an arbitrary polynomial of degree one, then derive the requirements of the coefficients, giving you the general form of a counterexample. Of course, I did this once, and my professor deducted points and wrote "make your counterexamples concrete." Take that as you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, considering it is a subset of a vector space, really there's only three things that can go wrong:

1) It isn't closed under addition,
2) It isn't closed under scalar multiplication, or
3) It's the empty set.

As it turns out, it isn't empty, and it is closed under scalar multiplication (a degree $n$ polynomial scaled by a non-zero scalar is still degree $n$, and when scaled by $0$, it is the zero polynomial). Therefore, really all you can do is show that it isn't closed under addition, and by far the simplest way of doing this is with a counterexample.

Comment: I'm looking to do it without a counterexample

Comment: May I ask why? I have a strong suspicion that the use of a counterexample could be avoided, but the proof won't be any nicer.

Comment: I agree, I just don't really like to rely on counterexamples.

Comment: You have no choice but to provide a counterexample, be it an explicit counterexample, or the general form of a pair of vectors that breaks addive closure. "Rely on counterexamples" - your request doesn't make sense.

Comment: OK, here's a proof: if it was a vector space, it would be a subspace of the polynomials. The space of polynomials of degree $2$ or less is also a subspace of the polynomials (of dimension $3$), so their intersection is a subspace, and is of dimension at most $3$. Since $x$ is not in the first subspace, but in the second, the dimension of the intersection is at most $2$. But, $x^2, x^2 + x, x^2 + x + 1$ are three linearly independent polynomials in the intersection, contradicting the dimension being at most $2$. Thus, the assumption that it was a subspace is incorrect.

Comment: I still stand by my statement that the counterexample is the nicest, simplest way to go about it, but (unlike what Jonathan Herbert is saying) non-constructive proofs are often possible.

Comment: Thanks for help me getting what I wanted instead of analyzing my request.

Comment: You technically still have a counterexample in your disproof in the comments (just a counterexample to another statement).

Comment: That is a proof by counterexample, it's just round-about.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: A counterexample to which statement?

Comment: "The dimension of the intersection is at most two." Which is exactly the same as "there does not exist a group of three or more linearly independent vectors", which you disproved by giving a counterexample.

Comment: So, to put it in terms of universal quantifiers, "for all bases for the intersection, the cardinality of the basis is at most $2$". But, as you might notice, I never once provided a counterexample basis. In fact, it would be impossible to do so, because the set itself is not a vector space! I still maintain it's non-constructive.

Comment: "The cardinality of any basis is at most two." "Therefore, there does not exist a set of three or more linearly independent vectors" (unstated, but the fact is used in your next line, it's why your contradiction is a contradiction) "Yes there does, here it is. Contradiction."

Comment: OK, so it depends on how you define dimension. The definition you decided to use (i.e. the infimal cardinality over all linearly independent sets) can be defined on any subset of a vector space. However, I don't think that it really validates the point that we are forced to provide some kind of counterexample somewhere along the line, because to interpret what I gave as a counterexample, it requires you to use one particular definition and extend it beyond its normal bounds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25507/discussion-between-theo-bendit-and-jonathan-hebert).

Comment: I'm just, in my mind, invoking theorems and definitions slightly differently to the way that you are. You filled the gaps in with your own steps, which were different to the steps in my head. Had I written every minute step down (impossible, given character restrictions), you would see that it is not a counterexample to that statement. Anyway, I do think we should use chat.

Comment: Look at what you said; "$x^{2}, x^{2}+x, x^{2}+x+1$ is a set of three linearly independent vectors in the intersection, contradicting the dimension being at most 2.", and now you're saying that you're neither involving the fact that "a dimension 2 vector space cannot have a set of three linearly independent vectors" (which you did when you said "a set of three linearly independent vectors in the intersection, contradicting the dimension being at most 2.") nor providing $x^{2}, x^{2}+x, x^{2}+x+1$ as a counterexample of the intersection's dimensionality?

Answer (score 1):

No. The only thing that this set is missing is closure under addition. It is closed under scalar multiplication, taking inverses and the null vector is included. It's even somewhat worse in that it is actually a ring and is closed even under multiplication defined as usual for polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

The additive property of a vector space is called a universal property (it uses the phrase "for all"):

For all $v,w\in V$, $v+w\in V$.  This means that the property must always be true, every time you add two vectors in the vector space, you must get a new vector.

To disprove a universal statement, one must show that it doesn't *always* happen.  In other words, that there is some case where it doesn't happen.  This is exactly what this contradiction proof does (and is the only way to disprove a universal statement).

Comment: This is the best answer, and it is down voted. Good job guys.

Answer (score 0):

No, nobody can do what you ask! The set *is* closed under scalar multiplication, so showing it's not a vector space is exactly the same as showing it's not closed under addition.